# VB - IndexOf always returns 0

Tags: vb.net, indexof

I was testing a way of interacting with save files for a game I am making, this method would import the file, line by line, to a list box which would be used for manipulation.

This simple test form adds text from a text box into a the list box, but if a line containing the new string already exists it should remove it before the new one is added.

However, the code as shown below will only ever return the index of 0

```
    Private Sub ... Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text

    'if exists
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(str) Then
        'find
        index = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(str)

        'remove
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(index)
    End If
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

No exceptions are thrown, but it does not remove the item.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data please? The content of the TextBox and the ListBox would be ideal

Comment: This sub is run at the press of a button, if the data does not exist in the list box it adds the contents it from the text box - last line of the sub - The string can be anything, I've been testing with just 'asd', but the content means nothing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `ListBox1.Items.Remove(index)`. Here you are calling the method to remove an item from the collection, but are passing it the index.

You should change to using either

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
```

or

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(str)
```

`RemoveAt` will remove an item from the specified `index`. `Remove` will look for an remove the specified item.

Comment: Amazing, Thank you for correcting my oversight! So this means that the index does indeed start from zero? Don't I seem a fool :)

Comment: Not at all! Because Remove takes an Object as a parameter, it happily accepted the index without error. A close inspection of the documentation would give you the answer but easy to miss if you don't know .RemoveAt exists

Comment: @JordanGray I am glad to be of assistance and don't worry about making the mistake, it's something that is very easily done. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and Up Vote it if you think the answer and the information is useful